# Flutter 'map' Dynamic call of null. Receiver: Instance of '_Future<dynamic>' Arguments: [Instance of '(dynamic) => Builder']

Tags: list, flutter, dynamic, carousel, future

i am trying to make a banner using this list which can be accessed with function "getBannerList" instead of having to manually write a list in this carousel

if i set items by manually putting a list at items: ['base64string','base64string','base64string'].map it will work fine but when i replace it with the function it causes this error

Error

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building MyApp(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery], state: _MyAppState#5a46f):
'map'
Dynamic call of null.
Receiver: Instance of '_Future<dynamic>'
Arguments: [Instance of '(dynamic) => Builder']
```

Code for carousel

```
Dependencies: carousel_slider: ^4.0.0

 CarouselSlider(
          options: CarouselOptions(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.15,
            autoPlay: true,
            autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 5),
            initialPage: 0,
          ),
          items: getBannerList().map((e) {   // <---- if i replaced this with ['asdf','asdf,'asdf].map((e) it works fine
            return Builder(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(image: MemoryImage(base64Decode(e.toString()))),
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
```

GetList Function

```
 getBannerList() async{
    dynamic data = await getDashBoardBannerData();
    print(data);
    return data;
  }
```

returns (example of return cause base64 string is too long):

```
['base64imgstring','base64imgstring','base64imgstring']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getBannerList` method returns `Future<dynamic>` not `List` :
1- change method signature to `Future<List<String>> getBannerList() async{}`
2- define a variable in your `StatefullWidget` called

```dart
late final Future<List> bannerList;
```

3- initialize you variable in init state

```dart
@override
void initState(){
 bannerList = getBannerList();
}
```

4- now we should use `FutureBuilder` with our `basserList`

```dart
FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
        future: bannerList, // your future data
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<String>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return CarouselSlider(
          options: CarouselOptions(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.15,
            autoPlay: true,
            autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 5),
            initialPage: 0,
          ),
          items: snapshot.data.map((e) {
            return Builder(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(image: MemoryImage(base64Decode(e.toString()))),
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Loading Error'); // error state
          } else {

          return CircularProgressIndicator(); // loading state
        },
```

you should use explicit types for fewer bugs.